# $a_n$=$\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2}\right)^2 \ldots\left(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2}\right)^n$ find limit of $a_n^{-\frac{1}{n^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $a_n$=$\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{2^2}{n^2}\right)^2 \cdot\left(1+\frac{3^2}{n^2}\right)^3 \ldots\left(1+\frac{n^2}{n^2}\right)^n$
then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n^{-\frac{1}{n^2}}$ ?

I am looking for Hints on this question.
By replacing all with $\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$  the only thing I get is upper bound 1.I have no idea how to proceed further .I need Hint on This.

Comment: Take the $\log$ of the limit first.

Comment: @RagibZaman Thank you  for your hint. Answer is $\frac {\sqrt{e}}{2}$ by taking log and using Reimann sum.

Comment: @MeetPatel,Avoid asking *no hint* questions in future,glad the hint given by other user helped you

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi You mean I should keep asking for Hints or I should avoid Hints?

Comment: @MeetPatel,I meant ,questions which don't show any work and simply state "I have no Idea" or "I have no hint" are Discouraged on This site, And other comment about The "Hint" was just an appreciation that Small hint led you to the Answer,Which means,If you would have put more work,You would have got it yourselves...